# Loop through keys in JSON array that start with specific key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there an efficient way to loop through the keys in a JSON array that start with the key name 'option' and either loop through them all or set a max?

I'm currently doing this following:

```
$.each(shopifyProductJSON.variants, function(index, variant) {
    variantOptions = new Array();
    variantOptions.push(variant.option1);
    variantOptions.push(variant.option2);
    variantOptions.push(variant.option3);
});
```

Which is fine but want it to be more dynamic in case more options are added in the future.

An example of part of the JSON array for each `variant`:

```
inventory_management: null
inventory_policy: "deny"
inventory_quantity: 0
old_inventory_quantity: 0
option1: "Bronze"
option2: "Satin Gold"
option3: "600mm"
position: 1
price: "550.00"
```

I thought this would've worked...

```
variantOptions = new Array();
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var key = 'option' + i;
    variantOptions.push(key);
}
```

Comment: Agreed. In the API for the restAPI they return them as those option1, option2 keys... which is stupid. In the JS API they return them as an array but for rate limits I'm dumping the JSON using the restAPI so I'm stuck with it. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your immediate issue you need to access the objects properties in the loop, not push the string in to the array:

```
let variantOptions = [];
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  var key = 'option' + i;
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    variantOptions.push(data[key]);
  }
}
```

That being said, if the options are going to be of a dynamic length it makes *far* more sense to return them as an array instead of individual numbered properties, assuming you have control over the response format.

You could change the response to this:

```
{
  inventory_management: null
  inventory_policy: "deny"
  inventory_quantity: 0
  old_inventory_quantity: 0
  options: ['Bronze', 'Satin Gold', '600mm'],
  position: 1
  price: "550.00"
}
```

Then the JS to access the options becomes a simple property accessor:

```js
let variantOptions = data.options;
```